# Need Design Pattern Suggestion

Tags: python, design-patterns, command-line-arguments

I need help para to beautify this code :)
The method definesAction will call a Class, based on the args. There is some way to  generalizing this piece of code, taking into account that the Class's are similar.
Thanks in advance

Main Class

```
def defineAction(args):

    if args.classabc is not None:
        for host in config.getList('ABC', 'hosts'):
            class_abc = ClassABC(config.getConfigs('ABC', host), args.version[0], user, password)
            class_abc.action(args.classabc)

    if args.classxyz is not None:
        for host in config.getList('XYZ', 'hosts'):
            class_xyz = ClassXYZ(config.getConfigs('XYZ', host), args.version[0], user, password)
            class_xyz.action(args.classxyz)

    # ...

def main():

    parser.add_argument('--classabc', choices=['cmd'])
    parser.add_argument('--classxyz', choices=['cmd'])
    # ...
    args = parser.parse_args()
    defineAction(args)
```

SubClasses

```
class ClassABC:
    def __init__(self, configs, user, password):
        self.hostConfigs = configs['host']
        self.host_username = user
        self.host_password = password

    def a_method(self):
        # This Method is equal in all subclasses
    def b_method(self):
        # This Method is different all subclasses

    def action(self, action):
        self.a_method()
        self.b_method()

        if action == 'cmd':
            self.execute_cmd()
```

Config FILE

```
[ABC]
hosts=abc_host1
var_abc=value1

[XYZ]
hosts=xyz_host1,xyz_host2
var_xyz=value2
```

Comment: Are the arguments exclusive, or can both `--classabc` and `--classxyz` be used at the same time?

Comment: they will only be used individually during a call, they will never be used simultaneously.

Comment: Your example uses `choices=['cmd']`, is that always the same, single string option for all `--class*` switches? Or is that going to vary?

Comment: What would the command-line switches look like, now you must use `--classabc cmd` or `--classxyz cmd` (no other versions allowed). What are the actual rules here, will there always be a required argument for a `--class*` switch?

Comment: This will be to define the behavior of some methods in the subclass, and will only pass a single value, or in the limit a dict. EDIT: I changed the example subclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working the assumption that the switches are mutually exclusive (in which case you really want to use a [mutually exclusive argument group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group)).

You want the argparser action to set the *class*. If your command-line switch doesn't need to take any arguments, then I'd use `action="store_const"` here:

```
parser.add_argument(
    '--classabc', dest="class_", const=ClassABC,
    action="store_const")
parser.add_argument(
    '--classxyz', dest="class_", const=ClassXYZ,
    action="store_const")
```

On parsing, the above actions set `args.class_` to `ClassABC` or `ClassXYZ` when one or the other switch is used. Give the classes a class method or an attribute to determine what configuration section to look in, do not hardcode those names anywhere else.

For instance, if both classes have a `config_section` attribute, (set to `'ABC'` for `ClassABC` and `'XYZ'` for `ClassXZY`), then you can use that attribute in your loop creating instances:

```
if args.class_:
    for host in config.getList(class_.config_section, 'hosts'):
        instance = args.class_(config.getConfig(class_.config_section, host), ...)
```

The idea is to not switch based on `args` attributes, you can leave this to `argparse` as it is already determining the different options for you.

If both command-line switches require an additional argument, then create a custom [`Action` subclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action-classes):

```
class StoreClassAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, **kwargs):
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, (self.const, values)
```

then use this as:

```
parser.add_argument(
    '--classabc', dest="class_", choices=['cmd'], const=ClassABC,
    action=StoreClassAction)
parser.add_argument(
    '--classxyz', dest="class_", choices=['cmd'], const=ClassXYZ,
     action=StoreClassAction)
```

Now the `args.class_` argument is set to `(classobject, argumentvalue)`, so you can use:

```
if args.class_:
    cls, action = args.class_
    for host in config.getList(cls.config_section, 'hosts'):
        instance = args.class_(config.getConfig(cls.config_section, host), ...)
        instance.action(action)
```

Comment: EDIT: I added the config file, with the information of the actions and their hosts. I'm not realizing how this info will be passed to the class and used by it

Comment: @tiago: give `ClassABC` an attribute `config_section` and set it to `'ABC'`, and do the same for `ClassXYZ` but set the attribute to `'XYZ'`. That attribute is then used to read the correct configuration section.